# Error al llamar funciones usando estructuras en C

Tags: c, funciones, estructuras-de-datos

Estoy muy confundido en este código. Me confundo porque si declaro primero mis funciones antes de las estructuras el error que me aparece es

*:6:13: error: unknown type name ‘paciente’*

Poniendo las funciones antes de las estructuras.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ncurses.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int menu();
void datos (paciente pac[]);

typedef struct signos_vitales
{
    int glucosa;
    float temperatura;
    float presion_d;
    float presion_s;
    int pulso;
}signos_vitales;

typedef struct paciente
{
    char paterno[50];
    char materno[50];
    char nombre[50];
    int edad;
    char sexo;
    bool asegurado;
    signos_vitales signos;
}paciente;

main()
{
    int num, m, seg, hiper, hipo;

    printf("Cuantos pacientes quieres registras\n");
        scanf("%d", &num);

    paciente pac[num];

    m = menu();

    switch(m)
    {
        case 1:
            datos(pac);
            break;
    }
}
```

Pero si cambio el orden y pongo las funciones después de las estructuras, al compilar, el error cambia y me aparece esto.

*In function main:*

*hospital.c:(.text+0x87): undefined reference to menu'*

*hospital.c:(.text+0x9e): undefined reference to datos'*

*collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status*

¿Qué es lo que estoy haciendo mal?

Answer (score 2):

Durante la fase de compilado el compilador (valga la redundancia), procesa los diferentes ficheros de código generando una suerte de código objeto. Para poder generar ese código objeto necesita conocer ciertos detalles de los tipos y funciones utilizadas para poder preparar las llamadas correctamente.

En el primer caso que comentas, "poner primero las funciones y después las estructuras", el problema que se encuentra el compilador es que las funciones hacen uso de las estructuras y, claro, el compilador desconoce totalmente el significado de `paciente`. ¿Es un alias?¿Es una estructura?¿Un puntero a función?¿una macro?. Como no lo conoce te muestra un error, aborta y se queda tan agusto. Es por este motivo que lo usual es poner las estructuras al principio y luego ya las funciones.

En el segundo caso lo que parece estar pasando es que el compilador ha terminado la fase de compilado correctamente, sin embargo en la fase de linkado no ha sido capaz de encontrar la implementación de `menu()`. Dado que en tu ejemplo no has puesto la implementación de dicha función la pregunta obvia es ¿Tienes en alguna parte la implementación de dicha función?

Si la respuesta es sí, entonces está claro que no se encuentra en el mismo fichero que la función `main()`, te falta un include para que el linker pueda hacer su trabajo.

Si la respuesta es no... te toca implementar la función para poder usarla.

(Y lo mismo para `datos()`)

Un saludo.